# Facebook PHP SDK v4: isValidRedirect() always return false

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

i tried to use the latest sdk of php to develop app with my website. but i always not get the correct session. then, i check the sdk file and found the isValidRedirect() return false. 
i tried to change the app setting, but not working for me.
so, guys, please check the attachment and where is wrong?

there is my code below:

// localhost/facebook/demo.php

```
<?php
@session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
// Skip these two lines if you're using Composer
require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

//require 'functions.php';  
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app_id','app_secrect' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://demo.localhost/facebook/demo.php/' );
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
echo '<hr />';
echo $loginUrl;
echo '<hr />';

try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    // $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    // print_r($request);
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    echo 22;
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    echo 33;
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo $helper->getLoginUrl(); ?>">Login with Facebook</a></div>
```

thanks.

php file url:
demo.localhost/facebook/demo.php

Secure Canvas URL:
demo.localhost/facebook/

Website:
site url:
demo.localhost/facebook/
Mobile Site Url:
demo.localhost/facebook/

Deauthorize Callback URL:
https://demo.localhost/facebook/

Comment: I am having the same problem, while my code was working fine yesterday. Can't understand what is wrong

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/33654680/1034359

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today, and I noticed that the state is always different between the one in the session and the returned state.

After a few googling, someone mentioned in another post
([PHP facebook SDK 4.0 login error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857368/php-facebook-sdk-4-0-login-error#comment36743906_23858057)) that the function getLoginUrl() changes state variable value. As suggested in that post and the comment, you need to move your `$helper->getLoginUrl()` after the `$helper->getSessionFromRedirect()`. It works for me.

I hope this helps.